# How to move applications between 2+ macs

Tags: macos, display

I have two macs. One is a MBP, the other one is a Mac mini. The Mac mini has two displays ( all OS X Mountain Lion). I use teleport to manage the the two computers and the three displays (1 MBP, 2 Mac Mini).

I would like to be able to move one application (ie one Google Chrome window) from one Mac to the other with a keyboard shortcut.

PS: I am NOT looking for apps like sizeup, spectacle, divvy. Tested them. They are not relevant to this use case.

Comment: Move or share aka screen sharing?

Comment: Move. No screen sharing.